# JW Player sendEvent does nothing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jwplayer

I've got JW Player events working in everything bar IE, and I can't work out why it won't pick the event up. In other browsers the click event causes the video to change using the value in the anchor click event, but in IE it does nothing.

The code is:

```
<div id="videoscreen"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jwPlayerInstance.sendEvent('load', '[URL TO VIDEO]'); jwPlayerInstance.sendEvent('play'); return false;" class="videoplayerlink">Load Video</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var jwPlayerInstance;
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    jwplayer("videoscreen").setup(
    {
        flashplayer: "/swf/player.swf",
        skin: "/swf/modieus.swf",
        file: "[URL TO VIDEO]",
        height: 190,
        width: 248,
        autostart: "false",
        wmode: "transparent",
        bgcolor: "#000000"
    }});

    jwPlayerInstance = document.getElementById('videoscreen');
}});
```

//]]>

Any ideas would be great!

Cheers, Ben

Comment: can you inspect the resulting swf object with IE then post the final HTML code ? with Firebug Lite maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try one of theese

1. delay your function
2. change the order of script and anchor
3. probably your objectSelection (getElemenyById) working before creation of object, try to organize it.

you may try

```
jwplayer("videoscreen").setup(
{
    flashplayer: "/swf/player.swf",
    skin: "/swf/modieus.swf",
    file: "[URL TO VIDEO]",
    height: 190,
    width: 248,
    autostart: "false",
    wmode: "transparent",
    bgcolor: "#000000"
},(function(){
 jwPlayerInstance = document.getElementById('videoscreen');
 })
);
```

by the way why there are double }} braces?

Comment: Apologies for late response. The double braces were because it was being set in a verbatim string in C#. I've set yours as the answer as it did the trick, thanks!